# Calculate the amount in select multiple, hide some elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

there is a form, I wrote a script that counts the sum from selects, but it does not count the amount in the multi-select, counts only one selected option, if it doesn’t count several more, tell me. please how can this issue be resolved

Also the question of how you can hide certain elements, that is, if the option `<option> 4 cylinders </option>` is selected in select "sel", then in select "sel1" leave only what is placed between the comments `<! - 4 cylinders-- > <! - end 4 cylinders ->` and hide everything else in select "sel1"

```html
<div class="cf-left-col">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="input-md form-control" id="sel">
      <option>Выберите количество цилиндров</option>
      <option>4 цилиндра</option>
      <option>6 цилиндров</option>
      <option>8 цилиндров</option>
      <option>ГАЗель</option>
    </select>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="input-md form-control" id="sel1">
      <option>Выберите оборудование</option>
      <!--4 цилиндра-->
      <option value="13000">OMVL SAVER-4 (Италия) - Лидер продаж в РФ</option>
      <option value="11700">Digitronic – (Польша)</option>
      <option value="7000">Atiker (Турция) – бюджетный комплет оборудования</option>
      <option value="12400">BRC- (Италия), Оборудование премиум класса)</option>
      <!--end 4 цилиндра-->
      <!--6 цилиндра-->
      <option value="17500">OMVL -6 (Италия), Лидер продаж в РФ</option>
      <option value="20800">OMVL -6 OBD (Италия) , Премиум линейка</option>
      <option value="28400">BRC- (Италия), Оборудование премиум класса</option>
      <!--8 цилиндра-->
      <option value="23000">OMVL -8 OBD (Италия) - Премиум линейка</option>
      <option value="33600">BRC- (Италия), Оборудование премиум класса</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="input-md form-control" id="sel2">
      <option>Выберите объем баллона</option>
      <option value="11275.29">Баллон (Метан) 50 л (219*1640) мм</option>
      <option value="29055.90">Баллон (Метан) 100 л( 425*1000) мм</option>
      <option value="25876.38">Баллон (Метан) 90 л (425*940) мм</option>
      <option value="4240.00">Баллон цилиндрический 100 л (399*895)</option>
      <option value="4310.00">Баллон 100 л (400*912)</option>
      <option value="4240.00">Баллон 103 л (356*1110) </option>
      <option value="4100.00">Баллон 105 л (376*1064)</option>
      <option value="4360.00">Баллон 130 л (399*1144) </option>
      <option value="4590.00">Баллон 130 л (400*1165)</option>
      <option value="7550.00">Баллон цилиндрический 200 л (498*1136) </option>
      <option value="2070.00">Баллон цилиндрический 35 л (241*880)</option>
      <option value="2520.00">Баллон цилиндрический 50 л (299*798) </option>
      <option value="2460.00">Баллон цилиндрический 50 л (300*796)</option>
      <option value="3240.00">Баллон цилиндрический 51 л (356*600) </option>
      <option value="2770.00">Баллон цилиндрический 60 л (299*948) </option>
      <option value="3070.00">Баллон цилиндрический 60 л (315*863) </option>
      <option value="2630.00">Баллон цилиндрический 60 л (300*945)</option>
      <option value="3000.00">Баллон цилиндрический 60 л (315*866)</option>
      <option value="2840.00">Баллон цилиндрический 65 л (299*1023) </option>
      <option value="4150.00">Баллон цилиндрический 80 л (356*900) </option>
      <option value="3520.00">Баллон тор внешняя горловина 42 л НЗГА (600*200)</option>
      <option value="5900.00">Баллон тор внешняя горловина 50 л (650*200) </option>
      <option value="4100.00">Баллон тор внешняя горловина 54 л НЗГА (630*220)</option>
      <option value="4710.00">Баллон тор внешняя горловина 60 л (630*250)</option>
      <option value="7550.00">Баллон тор внешняя горловина 62 л (720*210) </option>
      <option value="7500.00">Баллон тор внешняя горловина 74 л (720*230) </option>
      <option value="7900.00">Баллон тор внешняя горловина 81 л (720*250) </option>
      <option value="8350.00">Баллон тор внешняя горловина 98 л НЗГА (720*300)</option>
      <option value="3540.00">Баллон тор внутр. горловина 42 л НЗГА (600*200)</option>
      <option value="3990.00">Баллон тор внутр. горловина 47 л (600*220) </option>
      <option value="3730.00">Баллон тор внутр. горловина 53 л (630*225) </option>
      <option value="6620.00">Баллон тор внутр. горловина 54 л НЗГА (720*180)</option>
      <option value="6210.00">Баллон тор внутр. горловина 55 л (650*225) </option>
      <option value="8100.00">Баллон тор полнотелый 85 л (720*250) </option>
      <option value="8300.00">Баллон тор полнотелый 93 л (720*270) </option>
      <option value="8300.00">Баллон тор полнотелый 94 л (720*270) </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cf-right-col">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel3">
      <option value="300">ВЗУ</option>
      <option value="1000">Сенсор уровня газа</option>
      <option value="1500">Евромультиклапан</option>
      <option value="1500">Обтяжка карпетом</option>
      <option value="500">Доп фильтр тонкой очистки</option>
    </select>

  </div>
  <div class="form-tip pt-20">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Для множественного выбора зажмите клавишу CTRL
  </div>
</div>
```

My written handler

```js
function GetData() {
  var s = $('select').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    s.each(function() {
      sum += Number(this.value) || 0;
    });
    //$("#sum").html(sum);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Примерная стоимость установки: " + sum;
    console.log(sum);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is that every time the `change` event gets triggered on a select the `sum` variable is defined and assigned to zero inside the `change` callback function, I'd suggest to move this variable to the outer `GetData` scope:

```
function GetData() {
   var sum = 0;
   var s = $('select').change(function() {
         s.each(function() {
           sum += Number(this.value) || 0;
         });
         console.log(sum);
       });
  }
```

Regarding the other question you can add a handler to the `id=sel` select element that will get its value, then add a data attribute (`data-group`) to all option elements with a group id. Inside the handler for `sel` you'll query all elements with the group value `document.querySelectorAll('option[data-group="+ group_id +"]')` group_id will be set as an option value in `sel` and the hide all elements (`el.style.display = 'none'`)

I hope that helps

Comment: Unfortunately, no, in this case it sums up the values ​​very strange if we select something in select multiple

Comment: Mmm if you remove the each looping and only add the value every time a select is changed? having the `sum` variable defined in the `GetData` function? will that break the behavior you're expecting?

Comment: @jqutierrez Tell me, please, I decided to replace the multi-list with checkboxes, wrote a code in order to sum the values ​​of the checkboxes, how it can be combined with my code for selection
`$("input").click(function() {
                          var sum = 0;
                          $("input:checked").each(function(){
                          sum+= Number($(this).val());
                          });
                          console.log(sum)
                          });`

Comment: You should bind a `change` event to the input checkboxes to make it work.
`$("input").change(function() { var sum = 0; $("input:checked").each(function(){ sum+= Number($(this).val()); }); console.log(sum) });`
Sorry for the late response :(